# Regex ignore character with prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this js function:

`value.replace(/[\\\*\+\^\?\$\[\]\{\}\-]/g, '\\$&');`

which replace:

`* , + , ^ , ? , & , { , }`
with:
`\* , \+ , \^ , \? , \& , \{ , \}`

but when i have `.+` i need it to not be replaced with `.\+`

what do i need to change in my regex?

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you guys!  can anyone give me another site for regex learning?

Comment: Use `value.replace(/(\.\+)|[\\*+^?$[\]{}-]/g, function($0,$1) { return $1 ? $1 : '\\' + $0; });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply remove the `\+` from the regex, so that it forms: `value.replace(/[\\\*\^\?\$\[\]\{\}\-]/g, '\\$&');`